# How caret calculates R Squared

Tags: r-squared, caret, boosting

From the training output below, it looks like R squared is not calculated by the traditional formula 1 - SSE/SST, since lower error rate has lower R squared. So how is it calculated?

```
  colsample_bytree  min_child_weight  RMSE      Rsquared 
  0.4               3                 16963.39  0.8799191
  0.4               5                 16813.24  0.8788395
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code is here:

```
> R2
function(pred, obs, formula = "corr", na.rm = FALSE) {
    n <- sum(complete.cases(pred))
    switch(formula,
           corr = cor(obs, pred, use = ifelse(na.rm, "complete.obs", "everything"))^2,
           traditional = 1 - (sum((obs-pred)^2, na.rm = na.rm)/((n-1)*var(obs, na.rm = na.rm))))
  }
```

It follows the idea of calculating `R` then squaring it. There are a lot of formulas for `R^2` that can be used. See [Kvalseth. Cautionary note about R^2. American Statistician (1985) vol. 39 (4) pp. 279-285](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=14563234373759432258&hl=en&as_sdt=0,39). All of this is described at `?R2`.

Answer (score 2):

Update: The `R2` function is [deprecated](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/563). 
You can get R2 by the `postResample` function now.

The code is [here](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/pkg/caret/R/postResample.R) and shows in line 136 and 142 the formula:

```
resamplCor <- try(cor(pred, obs, use = "pairwise.complete.obs"), silent = TRUE
...
out <- c(sqrt(mse), resamplCor^2, mae)
```

So `postResample` uses the squared correlation to calculate R2.